# Attach entities with tree to EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have a huge form with many child entities, so, I fill EF object with tree using Automapper. Then I want to update similar entities in DB. Any way to attach its to context?

I try to do it by way:

```
        // ApplicationDriver has many child objects
        Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriver driver = mapper.Map<Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriver>(model);

        // get similar object from DB
        Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriver currentApplication = db.ApplicationDrivers.Where(p => p.ApplicationId == model.ApplicationId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (currentApplication == null)
        {
            db.ApplicationDrivers.Add(driver);
        }
        else
        {
            // try to attach driver to current context. 
            // I want to 'replace' current object with all child objects in DB
            db.ApplicationDrivers.Attach(driver);
            currentApplication = driver;
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get an error:

> "Attaching an entity of type 'Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriver'
>   failed because another entity of the same type already has the same
>   primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or
>   setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any
>   entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because
>   some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate."

I try:

```
        var currentApplication = db.ApplicationDrivers.Where(p => p.ApplicationId == model.ApplicationId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (currentApplication == null)
        {
            db.ApplicationDrivers.Add(driver);
        }
        else
        {
            driver.Id = currentApplication.Id;
            db.ApplicationDrivers.Attach(driver);
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

and get the same error. What is incorrect and how to solve this problem without manual copying each property for all child objects from driver to currentApplication?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RefactorThis.GraphDiff/

Comment: @IvanStoev. Very strange error: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated

Comment: This seems unrelated to the original issue. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an article:

https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code

seems, it would better don't use automapper to map DTO to EF for edit case..

Answer (score 0):

No need to attach to entity, if you want to update the DB, and replace the db with the current object :

```
    // ApplicationDriver has many child objects
    Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriver driver = mapper.Map<Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriver>(model);

    // get similar object from DB
    Infrastructure.Asset.ApplicationDriver currentApplication = db.ApplicationDrivers.Where(p => p.ApplicationId == model.ApplicationId).FirstOrDefault();

    if (currentApplication == null)
    {
        db.ApplicationDrivers.Add(driver);
    }
    else
    {
        //this will attach, and set state to modified
        //same as previous question, make sure you virtual properties are not populated to avoid unwanted duplicates. 
        db.Entry(driver).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; 
        currentApplication = driver;
    }
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```